# Fade effect on jquery step by step form

Tags: php, jquery

Good morning everyone,

I'm currently building a jquery step by step form at: http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/ and was just wondering how I could add an animation (i.e. fade in/fade out) between each step to ease the transition between each step?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is a solution http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/4/ . Simply replace hide by fadeOut and show by fadeIn. Hope it help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to add animation could be like this

```
 $(this).parent().parent().hide().prev().show('slow');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/6/

you can pass an argument to show that is the showing speed. If you also add jquery ui you can use various effects

```
 $(this).parent().parent().hide().next().show( 'slide', 'slow');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/7/

Answer (score 1):

As a start, you can try `show(300)` and `hide(300)` which will give you a basic animation.

See : http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/5/